# Custom Login with auth0

Tags: node.js, vue.js, express, auth0

I'm testing [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) and I'm wordering if I can custom the login auth0,validating users through my own postgres database?? I mean I have my own data base on postgres, and I would like validate user using my own database, it's possible???

and another one, I have my code backend on node js and express, if I configured [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for login users, validating users with my own database(postgres), then I have my code front on vue js, it's possible communicate my back with [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) validation and my front vue js???

I just create my back like:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session');
const passport = require('passport');
const Auth0Strategy = require('passport-auth0');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const cors = require('cors');
const pgSession = require('connect-pg-simple')(session);
const { Pool } = require('pg');
require('dotenv').config();
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');


//config cors
app.use(cors());

// Middleware JSON
app.use(express.json());

//PostgreSQL
const pool = new Pool({
    user: 'postgres',
    host: 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    database: 'namedatabase',
    password: 'password',
    port: 5432,
});

//sesión
app.use(session({
    store: new pgSession({ 
      pool, 
      tableName: 'session',
    }),
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  }));
  

//Passport
passport.use(
  new Auth0Strategy(
    {
        domain: process.env.AUTH0_DOMAIN,
        clientID: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_ID,
        clientSecret: process.env.AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET,
        callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/callback',
    },
    (accessToken, refreshToken, extraParams, profile, done) => {
      return done(null, profile);
    }
  )
);

// Passport
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

// Serialize y deserialize 
passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

// Middleware para asegurar rutas con Passport
const ensureAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req?.isAuthenticated()) {
      return next();
    }
    res.redirect('/login');
  };

// login router
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('auth0', { 
    scope: 'openid email profile',
}));

// profile
app.get('/profile', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.redirect('http://localhost:8081/profile');
});


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('');
});

// Rclose session
app.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  res.redirect('/');
});

// Callback Auth0 
app.get('/callback', (req, res, next) => { console.log("callback: ", req.user);
    passport.authenticate('auth0', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) {
        return next(err);
      }
      if (!user) {
        return res.redirect('/login'); // O redirige a otra página de error
      }
      req.logIn(user, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          return next(err);
        }
        return res.redirect('/profile');
      });
    })(req, res, next);
});

// start server
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

so, currently I'm getting the error that I can communicate with the front, so what can I do
to comunicate the back that run in port 3000 and my front that is running on port 8081 using my own database for validate users???